# DecimalFormat force latin numbers when users have different locales

Tags: java, android, formatting, number-formatting, numberformatexception

I am trying to parse a float while using a DecimalFormat twoDForm to reduce the number of decimals. 
To set the number of decimals I have instantiated as following:

```
twoDForm  = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

Then to parse the float I do call the following:

```
Float.valueOf(twoDForm.format(cameraPosition.x)
```

which in some cases seemingly based on locale throws

```
NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "١٥.٨٦" non latin numbers or font
```

I have been getting several different issues with NumberFormatException because of locales and differences in how Android devices are handling numbers and symbols, so I have also added the following to the DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
dfs.setMinusSign('-');
twoDForm.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

I've been able to solve the ones that involve some cases using different kinds of commas, and minus sign, but now I'm faced with this:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "١٥.٨٦"

When I google it I find arabic book suggestions so I'm guessing it's some other way of handling numbers for different languages. Is there any way to force that to use "regular" numbers to avoid that, which would allow me to simply call the same Float.valueOf(...) without having to add specific locales for each possible case?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with that text that yields the exception? What command are you invoking?

Comment: Just a note in case it's not clear in the question - those symbols are Arabic digits.

Comment: Is the `.` a regular period?

Comment: Probably.  An Arabic zero looks like a vertically-centred dot, so that's probably a decimal point.  So this looks  to me like `15.86`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters in that String are the Arabic digits for 1, 5, 8 and 6.  You'll need an Arabic-speaking locale to be able to parse them.

The following code works for me, and prints 15.86 as required.

```
Locale saudiArabia = new Locale("ar", "SA");
NumberFormat arabicFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(saudiArabia);
try {
    Number parsed = arabicFormat.parse("١٥.٨٦");
    System.out.println(parsed);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I have edited my question to be more specific, can you please look at it? Would there be any way I could simply account for any type of locale and then parse a string from a DecimalFormat? The problem is I have users all over the world and I won't know which locale they are using.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't really change the question substantially once people start answering - it invalidates their answers.  Remember that Stack Overflow is not just for you.  Other people will benefit from this question being here.  But that aside, why are you using a `DecimalFormat` to convert a number to a `String`, then `Float.valueOf` to convert it back into a number?  Can't you just leave it as a number, and avoid all these issues?

Comment: Yes, but I got a warning that the question had to be deleted because it was not properly formulated, and what I am asking here now is what I wanted to ask originally, I just asked it really really badly.. Anyways, it is because I want to limit the number of decimal places, and that was the only solution I came up with.

Comment: So your _real_ question is how to round a number to a certain number of decimal places?  And the whole business with locales and Arabic digits is a red herring?

Comment: Not really, I got the rounding part figured out, the problem is the one that arises when for some reason the DecimalFormat is used on a (in this case Android) device that has an arabic or any other locale so the Float parsing fails.

Comment: But if you did the rounding properly - for example, by writing `Math.rint(x * 100) / 100`, then the `Locale` would not be an issue.  Converting to a `String` and back is not a very good way to do rounding.

Comment: You're absolutely right. After converting to that method I no longer have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is from the fact that the device language is arabis. If so, automatically DecimalFormatSymbols will convert the latin numbers in arabic numbers. The best approach and the easiest on is to set the locale directly :

```
final DecimalFormatSymbols decimalSymbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
```